# Python: Plot step function for true/false signals

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a Python dictionary containing for each variable a tuple with an array of points in time and an array of numbers (1/0) representing the Boolean values that the variable holds at a certain point in time. For example:

```
dictionary["a"] = ([0,1,3], [1,1,0])
```

means that the variable `"a"` is true at both point in time 0 and 1, at point in time 2 `"a"` holds an arbitrary value and at point in time 3 it is false.

I would like to generate a plot using `matplotlib.pyplot` that will look somehow like this:
[image]
I already tried something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(1)
graphcount = 1
for x in dictionary:
    plt.subplot(len(dictionary), 1, graphcount)
    plt.step(dictionary[x][0], dictionary[x][1])
    plt.xlabel("time")
    plt.ylabel(x)
    graphcount += 1
plt.show()
```

but it does not give me the right results. For example, if `dictionary["a"] = ([2], [1])` no line is shown at all. Can someone please point me in the right direction on how to do this? Thank you!

Comment: Do you want a separate plot for each variable, or all plots on the lines on the same figure?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description the line should start at the first point and end at the last point. If the first and last points are the same then your line will be made of only one point. In order to see a line with only one point you need to use a visible marker.

Regarding the location of the jumps, the [docstring](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.step) says:

> where: [ ‘pre’ | ‘post’ | ‘mid’ ]
>
> If ‘pre’ (the default), the interval from x[i] to x[i+1] has level y[i+1].
>
> If ‘post’, that interval has level y[i].
>
> If ‘mid’, the jumps in y occur half-way between the x-values.

So I guess you want `'mid'`.

```
dictionary = {}
dictionary['a'] = ([0,1,3], [1,1,0])
dictionary['b'] = ([2], [1])

plt.figure(1)
graphcount = 1
for x in dictionary:
    plt.subplot(len(dictionary), 1, graphcount)
    plt.step(dictionary[x][0], dictionary[x][1], 'o-', where='mid')
    plt.xlabel("time")
    plt.ylabel(x)
    graphcount += 1
plt.show()
```

[image: step_mid]

Comment: Thank you - that already helps. However, I would like the line to continue over the whole time frame. Thus I would like to not just have one point for variable `b` but have a continuous false signal. I guess my example was not chosen well for this case. Also, for variable `a` with your example it is not clear whether a is true or false at point 1. This is why I would like the steps to be always in between whole time points, thus at 0.5, 1.5, 2.5 and so on. How do I do this?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "the whole time frame". You only gave one point for `b` so how could the program guess what the time frame is? Please clarify this in the question. See my edit about the location of the steps.